# R-ArcGIS: Impossible to perform dplyr join with data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, arcgis

I've just begun to use the R-ArcGIS bridge package `arcgisbinding` and am running into a problem when I try to join feature class data with the `dplyr` package. Here is an example where I'm trying to get the ozone columns from two shapefiles into a single data frame, then export back as a shapefile.

```
library(dplyr)
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()

fc <- arc.open(system.file("extdata", "ca_ozone_pts.shp",
                       package="arcgisbinding"))
d <- arc.select(fc, fields=c('FID', 'ozone'))
p<-arc.select(fc,fields=c('FID', 'ozone'))
p$ozone<-p$ozone*2
p<-left_join(p,d,by="FID")
arc.write(tempfile("ca_new", fileext=".shp"), p)
# original dataframe has shape attributes
str(d)
# new dataframe does not
str(p)
```

From the `arcgisbinding` package, `p` and `d` above are data frame objects with shape attributes. The problem is that once I use `left_join`, I lose the spatial attribute data in the joined data frame. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this is a known problem ([see GitHub here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/196578-impossible-to-use-dplyr-join-functions-on-data-frames?et=watches.email.outcome)).

A workaround using the `spdplyr` package comes by way of Shaun Wallbridge on ESRI GeoNet ([link to thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/196578-impossible-to-use-dplyr-join-functions-on-data-frames?et=watches.email.outcome)). Basically, convert the arc.data data frame into an sp object, perform analyses, then export as a feature class or shapefile.

```
library(spdplyr)
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()

fc <- arc.open(system.file("extdata", "ca_ozone_pts.shp", package="arcgisbinding"))
d <- arc.select(fc,fields=c('FID', 'ozone'))
d.sp <- arc.data2sp(d)

p <-arc.select(fc,fields=c('FID', 'ozone'))
p.sp <- arc.data2sp(p)
p.sp$ozone <- p$ozone*2

joined <- left_join(p.sp, d.sp, by="FID", copy=TRUE)
joined.df <- arc.sp2data(joined)

arc.write(tempfile("ca_ozone_pts_joined", fileext=".shp"), joined.df)
```